# Avoid returning to previous activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, fragment, softkeys

I have an app that at the start checks if the user is logged and acts in two ways:

1) jumps the registration/login activity starting directly from the second activity if the user is logged in

2) let the user do the registration/login process starting from the relative activity

But I have a problem: if the user is logged in(and the app starts directly from the second activity) and presses the back soft key, the app shows the registration/login activity.

How can I avoid it?

I was thinking about modifying the softkey behaviour by calling `onBackPressed()` in the second activity, but I think it's not so right...

Comment: You can Activity.finish() you activity once you are done with it. This could help.

Comment: simply call finish();

Comment: it still returns to the first activity. I had to edit the manifest with the android:noHistory element :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's assume your have your `StartActivity`, that has the logic of opening `LoginActivity` or `MainActivity`.
TO you AndroidManifest.xml add the following XML:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

and in your `StartActivity`, after calling `startActivity(newActivityIntent)` call `finish()`.
Example:

```
Intent intent;
if (isLoginRequired) {
    intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: didn't know about android:noHistory. Thanks a lot :D
I'd vote you up but I don't have the required reputation :|

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is start the second activity by `startActivityForResult()` and override `onActivityResult`. when you return from second activity if it is logout use a separate requestCode and for the other one i.e. back button pressed override it as `finish()`.